# Make foreach show one by one within javascript loop?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm trying to display latest posts from multiple categories in the page by using foreach within javascript loop, but instead one by one the foreach display them all as in the picture below:

[image]

I want to display it one every element, not all of them in every element.

```
for (var i in books) { //Start JS Code
    var html = '<div class="row"><div class="book_history">';
        // JS Output

    <?php // Start PHP
    $catids = array(39, 37, 2); // Category for test
    foreach ( $catids as $catid ) {

        $my_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'cat' => $catid,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'no_found_rows' => true ) 
        );

        if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :

                while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                    html += '<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">»Chapter <?php the_title(); ?></a></div>'; // Javascript Code, Displaying the result of foreach with js
            <?php endwhile;

        endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();
    } ?> // End PHP

        $bookcontainer.append(html); // Insert all result of foreach and js into some element

} // End JS Code
```

Is there any solution for this?
*The order of categories with JavaScript is same.

Comment: mixing JS+HTML+PHP in one block of code is a very bad practice, you can use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)#Javascript example instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP is rendered server side, you cant combine it in that way with JavaScript.

But you could pass JSON to JavaScript to parse the structure and display it on the website.

Imagine you have the following array with your data:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'category_id' => 39,
        'chapters' => array(
            array(
                'link' => 'http://google.de',
                'chapter_name' => 'First chapter',
            )
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'category_id' => 37,
        'chapters' => array(
            array(
                'link' => 'http://google.de',
                'chapter_name' => 'Second chapter',
            )
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'category_id' => 42,
        'chapters' => array(
            array(
                'link' => 'http://google.de',
                'chapter_name' => 'Third chapter',
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```

You can simply output the JSON representation of this array with `json_encode($data)` (make sure to echo it into a JS variable).

Then you can easily read it out with JavaScript. Here is a nice codepen: https://codepen.io/YannickFricke/pen/Vqzoob

A quick note about the forEach function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: So, I get the latest posts of the category then convert them into json array, right?

Comment: Right. You can pass any structure as array to `json_encode`. `json_encode` automatically determines how to parse the array and returns the JSON representation for it. You can then process it on the website and show your values :) And please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: it's still displaying all of them since I have different variable json, any solution for this?

Comment: You can filter the entries based on the category_id with https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter. Then you only have the entries for the current category_id. Ask a new question with the new problem and feel free to comment here, so I can take a look on it if you want :)

Comment: I'm still doesn't understand, so I have same category ids with other json (for example 39, 37, 2). I'm tried with if (history.id == book.id) if its same then display the output, but it only displayed once after that the looping is stopped.

Comment: Whether history nor book are defined in your code. Please ask a new question with the new interrogation. :)

Comment: I post the new question :)