# For loop with different json variable display all items instead one each

Tags: javascript, json

So according to my previous answered question ([Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53954051/make-foreach-show-one-by-one-within-javascript-loop))

I create second json variable with data from php that I sending to js variable, so I already have a show that display last where user read the posts like this:

```
 [ //defined by var = book | remove url for privacy reason.
    {
        "id": 39,
        "title": "My Pet",
        "url": "https:///novel/my-pet/",
        "chapter": {
            "id": 1192,
            "title": "35",
            "url": "https:///my-pet-35/"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 37,
        "title": "Nobunaga’s Imouto",
        "url": "https:///novel/nobunagas-imouto/",
        "chapter": {
            "id": 1449,
            "title": "2",
            "url": "https:///nobunaga-imouto-2/"
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Duke's Daughter",
        "url": "https:///novel/dukes-daughter/",
        "chapter": {
            "id": 1398,
            "title": "99",
            "url": "https:///dukes-daughter-99/"
        }
    }
]
```

The first json get the data from cookies, so the user can track their last read.
and as for my second json variable are display the newest of a post from category

```
[ //defined by var = newest
    {
        "id": 39,
        "title": "My Pet Chapter 35",
        "url": "https:///my-pet-35/",
    },
    {
        "id": 37,
        "title": "Nobunaga’s Imouto Chaoter 4",
        "url": "https:///nobunaga-imouto-4/",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Duke's Daughter Chapter 106",
        "url": "https:///dukes-daughter-106/",
    }
]
```

Then I display them with for loop:

```
    $bookcontainer = $('#release_history'); 
    for (var i in books) {
        var book = books[i];
        var html = '<div class="row"><div class="book_history">';
        html += '<a href="'+book.url+'">'+book.title+'</a></div>';

         // Display last user read from json

        html += '<div class="newest_history">';
        for (var j in newest) { // display the newest of a post from category
            var news = newest[j];
            html += '<a href="'+news.url+'">»Chapter '+news.title+'</a></div>';
        }
        html += '</div></div></div>';
        $bookcontainer.append(html);
    }
```

But it will showing like this: 
[image]

So I thought to add if conditional, if the two ids are equal.

```
            for (var j in newest) {
            var news = newest[j];
            if (news.id == book.id){
                html += '<a href="'+news.url+'">»Chapter '+news.title+'</a></div>';}
            }
```

However, the loop is stopped after display the first output.
Is there any solution for this? to keep all of them separate while displaying? I want to display the newest chapter/posts of the categories, so the user can know there is new chapter on their last read book.

Comment: just something I noticed. Don't use `new` as a variable name. `new` is a reserved keyword

Comment: no, I don't use it on the code. just make clear that the new is second variable, I will change the word.

Comment: Also, `new.link` and `new.chapter` are undefined. There are no such keys in your data, therefore nothing shows up :)

Comment: ahhh, sorry it typo. it not real my code, I recreate the code.

Comment: If you don't provide the code you have problems with, we're gonna have a hard time helping :) As a sidenote, you can directly iterate the objects themselves (not the _indexes_ of the objects) using `for (let obj of newest)`

Comment: it fine, the real code it's not really different (name of element). the difference is only on json. Thanks, i will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by change:

```
for (var j in newest)
```

to

```
for (var j = 0; j < newest.length; j++)
```

I felt wrong that to only use `var j in` in the second loop like that

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if the `index` id of those two objects are same like if the `id` at `index:0` and `id` at `index:3` are same then also it wont display it since you are not checking if it contains or not:

Try this:

```js
var book = [ //defined by var = book
    {
        "id": 39, //Category ID
        "title": "Last Read A",
        "url": "Chapter URL A",
    },
    {
        "id": 37, //Category ID
        "title": "Last Read B",
        "url": " Chapter URL C",
    },
    {
        "id": 2, //Category ID
        "title": "Last Read C",
        "url": " Chapter URL C",
    }
]

var book1 = [ //defined by var = newest
    {
        "id": 39, //Category ID
        "title": "Newest Chapter A",
        "url": "Post URL Chapter A",
    },
    {
        "id": 37, //Category ID
        "title": "Newest Chapter B",
        "url": " Post URL Chapter C",
    },
    {
        "id": 2, //Category ID
        "title": "Newest Chapter C",
        "url": " Post URL Chapter C",
    },
    
 //Added a different book with id 10
    {
        "id": 10, //Category ID
        "title": "Newest Chapter C",
        "url": " Post URL Chapter C",
    }
]

const bookIds = book1.map(bookData => bookData.id);

console.log('BookIDS:', bookIds)


book.forEach(bookData => {
  if(bookIds.indexOf(bookData.id) > -1){
    console.log('Matching book found with ID:', bookData.id);
  }
})
```

Comment: forEach is not a function. the json of book is already an object though...

Comment: but the BookIDS it's working: ["39", "40", "37", "2"]

Comment: book.forEach is not a function.

Comment: yes, I use js-cookie to store last read user to cookie after that use Cookies.getJSON that will parse the cookie into an object array, I'm also tried to parse it again after get the json but got error [object object] on the inspect.

Comment: Can you paste your book data where you are getting `book.forEach` is not a function

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Mzc1kcWD . I remove my website URL for privacy reason.

Comment: The `Raw Paste Data` contains an array how you are using it?

Comment: I using it by looping the json with for loop, I updated the code on the question.

Comment: so inside this:   for (var j in newest) {
            var news = newest[j];
            if (news.id == book.id){
                html += '<a href="'+news.url+'">»Chapter '+news.title+'</a></div>';}
            }

you are using `book.forEach`

Comment: I don't add that code to question, only $bookcontainer and html += (after var html)

Comment: Got it instead of this ` var book = books[i];` try  `books.forEach`

Comment: sorry, I do not understand what you mean? so I change the entirely the loop into forEach?

Comment: then do `books.forEach` because you don't have any book variable in the code you are getting error.

Answer (score 0):

So you only want to know which books are unread by the current user?

```
const books = [ //defined by var = book
    {
        "id": 39, //Category ID
        "title": "Last Read A",
        "url": "Chapter URL A",
    },
    {
        "id": 37, //Category ID
        "title": "Last Read B",
        "url": " Chapter URL C",
    },
    {
        "id": 2, //Category ID
        "title": "Last Read C",
        "url": " Chapter URL C",
    }
];

const newest = [ //defined by var = newest
    {
        "id": 39, //Category ID
        "title": "Newest Chapter A",
        "url": "Post URL Chapter A",
    },
    {
        "id": 37, //Category ID
        "title": "Newest Chapter B",
        "url": " Post URL Chapter C",
    },
    {
        "id": 2, //Category ID
        "title": "Last Read C",
        "url": " Chapter URL C",
    },

    //Added a different book with id 10
    {
        "id": 10, //Category ID
        "title": "Newest Chapter C",
        "url": " Post URL Chapter C",
    }
];

newBooks = newest.filter(function (element) {
    return books.filter(function (book) {
        if (element.id !== book.id) {
            return false;
        }

        if (element.title !== book.title) {
            return false;
        }

        return element.url === book.url;
    }).length === 0;
});

console.log(newBooks);
```

The filter function allows you to filter entries where the condition is true.

In this sample I check the size of the filtered book array to equal zero.

When it is zero, the user didn't read the new chapters.

So the filtered book array give me then entries which are not equal to the current entry of the "newest" array.

Output of the sample:

```
[ { id: 39, title: 'Newest Chapter A', url: 'Post URL Chapter A' },
{ id: 37, title: 'Newest Chapter B', url: ' Post URL Chapter C' },
{ id: 10, title: 'Newest Chapter C', url: ' Post URL Chapter C' } ]
```

As you can see the entry with the id "2" is filtered, because they have the same data.

Comment: No, not like that. I use cookie, so user can track their last read the chapter. the newest chapter will keep displaying even their last read it's same with newest. Chapter 26 (Last Read) | Chapter 26 (Newest Chapter)

Comment: Then you should be more concise in your question. It's hard to understand what you want and what you have.

Comment: I'm not really good at english, so maybe my question will be unclear. Well, I will keep that in mind to correct myself.

Comment: Then you could add to your question what you want and what you want to have (current / expected result)

Comment: It still does not contains your expected result. What should the script do?

Comment: I want to display the newest chapter/posts of the categories, so the user can know there is new chapter on their last read book. all of them keep displaying every when the user checks their last read.

Comment: And what is your data structure? The pastebin link also should be included in the first post. You need to provide as much as informations as you can. Otherwise we cant help you.